# What is an "X11 platform" and can it run on windows?

Tags: x11, gtk3

I'm trying to get [GtkPlug and GtkSocket](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/PlugSocket.html) to work on Windows 8, using the [currently supported GTK3+ windows bundle](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php).

I see in the documentation this note:

> The GtkPlug and GtkSocket widgets are only available when GTK+ is
>   compiled for the X11 platform and GDK_WINDOWING_X11 is defined. They
>   can only be used on a GdkX11Display. To use GtkPlug and GtkSocket, you
>   need to include the gtk/gtkx.h header.

What is an X11 platform, and can it be run on windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X11 is the graphics platform used by Linux and other Unix-style OSes. It is available for Windows through the Cygwin package but binaries compiled under Cygwin will not run on Windows without Cygwin installed so you probably don't want to go down that path. The documentation is essentially saying "this feature is only available on Linux."